# Check which profile set my PATH when startup

Tags: linux, bash

Something set my PATH, but after googled and checks, I've found nothing. I want to know how to analysis what changed my PATH actually.

I checked `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_login`, `/etc/environments`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d`, and tried to source them after unset PATH, but I'm still not found the thing that I don't expected to appear in my PATH.

```
/home/myusername/.yarn/bin:/home/myusername/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/bin:/home/myusername/.
opam/something/bin:/home/myusername/.yarn/bin:/home/myusername/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/
opt/cuda/bin:/home/myusername/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/co
re_perl:/home/myusername/.cargo/bin:/home/myusername/dev/mbed/lib/something2/bin:/home/myusername/go/bin:/home/myusername/dev/**something3**/bin **:/opt/cuda/bin:/home/myusername/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_pe
rl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/myusername/.cargo/bin:/home/myusername/dev/mbed/lib/something2/bin:/h
ome/myusername/go/bin**
```

I don't expected:

```
/opt/cuda/bin:/home/myusername/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_pe
rl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/myusername/.cargo/bin:/home/myusername/dev/mbed/lib/so
mething2/bin:/home/myusername/go/bin
```

occurred twice and the occurrence of something3.

How do I analyze and fix it?

Comment: Potentially useful although might not be a direct answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash

Comment: Have you tried unsetting PATH then sourcing the configuration files one by one and PATH?

Comment: `grep -IR 'export PATH' ~/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shell is `bash`, you can invoke it with flags `--login -x` to see a trace of everything evaluated during startup:

```
user@machine:~$ bash --login -x
+ eval 'PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"'
...
```

Since you've already checked the files that are sourced directly by `bash`, the PATH changes you're seeing are likely coming from an indirect `source`. The `source` invocation will show up in the trace as `. /path/to/evil_path_manipulator.sh`.